I have a welder with overvoltage damage: main control board with issues
I got a Lincoln Electric SP-175 Plus 230 V single phase welder that got plugged into 480 V some how.
How do I know what size of trace replacement wire to use?



the size of the component leads

With at least two traces blown, chances are the overvoltage got past "surge protection". I wouldn't use any of the electronics where there is the slightest chance of something catching fire, or dangerous fumes hurting anyone.
